# Trouble Installing React as an App within Django

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework

I am using this tutorial to install React for the front with an API built in Django.

https://sweetcode.io/how-use-djang-react-ap/

My repository for this projects so far is here:

https://github.com/AlexMercedCoder/DjangoReactCRM

I am at the point in the tutorial where you install react by running "npm run dev"

This is the error I get and no tinkering with the relative file page seems to fix it:

```
> webpack --mode development ./frontend/src/components/index.jsx --output 
./frontend/static/frontend/main.js


Insufficient number of arguments or no entry found.
Alternatively, run 'webpack(-cli) --help' for usage info.

Hash: 097c83a63f327afef15a
Version: webpack 4.39.3
Time: 80ms
Built at: 09/07/2019 4:16:05 PM

ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve 
'./frontend/src/components/index.jsx' in 
'C:\Users\alexm\projects\DjangoReactCRM\drcrm'
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! drcrm@1.0.0 dev: `webpack --mode development 
./frontend/src/components/index.jsx --output 
./frontend/static/frontend/main.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the drcrm@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely 
additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\alexm\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-09- 
07T20_16_05_497Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error states, you don't have a file called `./frontend/src/components/index.jsx` in your project - https://github.com/AlexMercedCoder/DjangoReactCRM/tree/master/frontend/src/components. It is `index.js` instead.

So, in your package.json, change the script to be:

```
webpack --mode development ./frontend/src/components/index.js --output ./frontend/static/frontend/main.js
```